# I have forgotten my user name for my mac

Tags: macbook-pro, username

I have a mac-book pro and I've lost my user name to get into the computer, how can I fix this problem without taking it to our Apple agents who are soooo slow,
Thanks

Comment: You can find a detailed walkthrough [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1274)

Answer (score 11):

You can get into single user mode using `Command+S` while booting, then run `ls /Users` and it should show all the users which will give you a good idea of which one is you.

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then type `ls /users` to see a list of all accounts on the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and type the command:

```
whoami
```

This will return your own username.

Comment: The asker’s problem is that they cannot log in, which is required to do this.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft maybe so, but it does answer the title of the post, which is what most search engines will respond to!